# Is hard limit of file descriptor changed in ruby 2.2?

Tags: ruby, unix, file-descriptor

I use `p Process.getrlimit(:NOFILE)` to get limit of file descriptor in my machine, I get

[1024, 4096]

shouldn't the hard limit be `Process::RLIMI_INFINITY` if I don't change the limit(accroding to book Working with unix process)?

I use ruby 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux 3.0 or newer the default hard ulimit is 4096. See this [commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0ac1ee0bfec2a4ad118f907ce586d0dfd8db7641). The author of the book probably used some other Unix-like operating system where it's indeed `Process::RLIM_INFINITY`.